# Unexpected behavior of Partitioner

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

This is my partitioner code

```
public int getPartition(Text key, IntWritable value, int i) {

    String s = key.toString();

    if(s.length()==1)
        return 0;
    if(s.length()==2)
        return 1;
    if(s.length()==6)
        return 2;
    else 
        return 3;}
```

As per it i need 4 reducer to work properly.

1. As per my understanding if i define any less number of reducer in driver class I will gete IO exception and job will fail.
2. If i define more number of reducer than required extra reducers will create empty output files but no exceptions are thrown.

What i didnt understand is if i dont define any number of reducer in Driver file . It should fail as by default number of Reducer is 1 but to my astonishment it worked.

Job ran and created 1 output file.
Can anyone shed some light on why and how it is working ?

Comment: And in the single file it produced did it contain all of your data or just the data your custom partitioner sent it?

Comment: The file created contained all the data , could it be possible it didnt use explicitly defined  Partitioner class as I didnt define no of reducer